# Hash merge with one of hash having key as a symbol

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hash in Ruby like this

```
hash1={"a" = > "b"}
hash2={:a => "c" }
```

When I am doing 
hash1.merge!(hash2) I am getting the result as

```
{"a"=>"b", :a=>"c"}
```

I want to   get the result as   `{"a" => "c"}` basically I want ruby to treat symbol and string as same for key value.

I was looking into Hash class and could not find any way to do so.

Question is how can I merge such that result of above operation is {"a" => "c"}.

Comment: If you found at least one of the answers to be helpful, please consider choosing the one you liked best.

Answer (score 9):

The `ActiveSupport` gem has the [`Hash#stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys) method that helps in this case:

```
require 'active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access'

hash1 = { "a" => "b" }
hash2 = { :a  => "c" }

hash1.merge(hash2.stringify_keys)
# => { "a" => "c" }
```

This is how the method is implemented (simplified):

```
class Hash
  def stringify_keys
    {}.tap do |result|
      each_key { |key| result[key.to_s] = self[key] }
    end
  end
end
```

**Update** Ruby 2.5.0 introduced [`Array#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) that would allow stringifying keys in a hash like this:

```
hash1 = { "a" => "b" }
hash2 = { :a  => "c" }

hash1.merge(hash2.transform_keys(&:to_s))
# => { "a" => "c" }
```

That means there is no need to use `ActiveSupport` anymore.

Comment: I am not using rails. Is there any other way to stringify_keys.

Comment: You could reimplement that feature by duplicating the source code from that gem. Or just use the ActiveSupport gem without Rails.

Comment: You don't need to use Rails. Just install the Gem and use it.

Comment: @user27111987 Updated my answer with a pure Ruby version that works with Ruby >= 2.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

You could normalise hash keys to the same kind (i.e. `to_s` or `to_sym`) and merge:

```
h = lambda { |h| Hash[h.map{ |k,v| [k.to_s, v] }] }
hash1 = h.call(hash1)
hash2 = h.call(hash2)
hash1.merge!(hash2)
```

Alternatively define lambda using shorthand:

```
h = -> (h) { Hash[h.map{ |k,v| [k.to_s, v] }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

In view of the fact that you want to modify `hash1` (rather than create a new hash), you could do this:

```
hash1     = { "a" => "b", "d" => "e" }
hash2     = { :a  => "c", :f => "g", :h => "i", "j" => "k" }
stringify = [ :a, :f ]

hash2.each { |k,v| hash1[stringify.include?(k) ? k.to_s : k] = v }
hash1
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "d"=>"e", "f"=>"g", :h=>"i", "j"=>"k"}
```

If all keys in `hash2` that are symbols are to be converted to strings:

```
hash2.each { |k,v| hash1[k.to_s] = v }
hash1
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "d"=>"e", "f"=>"g", "h"=>"i", "j"=>"k"}
```